# Types of ArraysLists

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

There is a way you can make `Array`s inside another `Array`/`ArrayList`, being of different type? Example: If I want to make an `ArrayList` with names of classes, and inside each index, an `Array` with its stats.

Comment: While it is possible creating an array of Object it is not a good data structure to handle your data.

Comment: I suggest looking at dictionaries, you can use the index in any way you like, where you can use the value like a list (or the Java variant). It's not particularly efficient however.

I suggest that you give more information, as there usually is a better way of doing stuff.

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO And what would be an efficent way to create classes like i mentioned previously?

Comment: You seem to be thinking about a *map* rather than a *list*. A map is a data structure where you find an object (*value*) by a given *key*. A list is an ordered collection of items of the same type.

Comment: Create a custom class that hold the data that you need. For example a class that has information related to the name and to the statistics, suppose you name this class Team then you can create a List or an array of Team

Comment: @Nickvda Sure, what i want to do its most efficient way to create classes, each with his name obviusly in string form, and with his stats in double type.

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO The problem its i need to make a big amount of classes, i just wanted to know most efficient way.

Comment: @RealSkeptic From what i understand, maps can contain 2 variables, if i want to set a name, attack, hp, defense, etc, i don't think maps could help me.

Comment: That's why you create *objects* in Java. You put all the needed information about a specific entity in an object, and then you can put that object in any collection.

Comment: So, look for a dictionary (or Hashmap).

Comment: @RealSkeptic So i create different objects representating different classes and then i call their variables from the "engine" of the game? thanks, i think i understand.

Comment: A big amount of classes? How many? Hundreds?

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO Nah not so much, maybe 20 for future games when im more advanced, but its easier get variables from arrays than make large "if" sentences, when player it's selecting the class. Anyway i already got responded, thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to handle only twenty different data structures the best in terms of readability is to create a custom class for each data structure. Eventually consider to create gerarchies of classes and common interfaces.

---

If you need to build a generic data structure to hold different kind of data you can use different techniques.

If you don't care on the order of fields you can use a simple Map like the following:

```
Map<String, Object> complexObject = new HashMap<>();
complexObject.put("name", "John");
complexObject.put("lastName", "Smith");
complexObject.put("age", 30);
```

If you need to mantain the order of fields you can use [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html):

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Map interface, with predictable iteration order.

This data structure can hold also nested levels, for example:

```
Map<String, Object> person = new HashMap<>();
person.put("name", "John");
person.put("lastName", "Smith");
person.put("age", 30);

Map<String, Object> address = new HashMap<>();
address.put("city", "Rome");
address.put("country", "Italy");

person.put("address", address);

List<String> preferredColors = new ArrayList<>();
preferredColors.add("Red");
preferredColors.add("Blue");

person.put("preferredColors", preferredColors);
```

Eventually you can consider also to hide the Map inside a custom class "*ComplexData*" that expose only methods to add or set a property and get a property, eventually adding specific method to retrieve primitive data types so you don't need to manually cast the returned values.